# How to find the value based on two columns

Tags: r

The data set is:

```
col_1,col_2,value
8521,13394,24
8521,14353,15
...
1112074,1112073,52
```

I want a lookup for a number in the value column given numbers for the first two columns.
I know using data.frame or array can solve this problem. But the maximum value in col_1 or col_2 is so big that I cannot build a 1112074*3 data.frame.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for.

Comment: Could you re-phrase the question to make it a little more clear?

Comment: Make a 1112074*2 data.frame having col_1 and col_2. Value can be calculated when required.

Comment: Sorry. I rephrased the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you want a lookup for a number in the value column given numbers for the first two columns

Here's one way using a simple data.frame and a loop-up function

```
dd<-data.frame(
   col_1 = c(8521, 8521, 1112074),
   col_2 = c(13394, 14353, 1112073),
   value = c(24,15,52)
)

getval<-function(c1,c2, data=dd) {
    data$value[data$col_1==c1 & data$col_2==c2]
}

getval(8521, 14353)
# [1] 15
```

Unfortunately this procedure isn't very fast. If you plan to do this often, you might consider using the `data.table` library which allows you to index your table for faster look-up

```
library(data.table)
dt<-data.table(
   col_1 = c(8521, 8521, 1112074),
   col_2 = c(13394, 14353, 1112073),
   value = c(24,15,52)
)
setkey(dt, col_1, col_2)

getval<-function(c1,c2, data=dt) {
    dt[.(c1,c2)][, value]
}
getval(8521, 14353)
# [1] 15
```